# check password linux user

Tags: linux, bash, perl, encryption

I am on debian 9. 
I have a problem to check the password of a linux user in my scripts. I realized that the different linux tools for creating and modifying a user password gave results of different pattern in `/etc/shadow`

**To create a user**

```
pwLinux="abcdef1234"
userLinux="toto02"
pwCrypt=$(perl -e 'print crypt($ARGV[0], "zzz")' $pwLinux)
useradd -m -G adm,dip,plugdev,www-data,sudo -p $pwCrypt $userLinux
```

I have in `/etc/shadow`

```
toto02:zzDxrNjXuUs3U:17469:0:99999:7:::
```

In another script I want **check the password** input by the user with

```
USERNAME="toto02"
PASSWD="abcdef1234"
ORIGPASS=`grep -w "$USERNAME" /etc/shadow | cut -d: -f2`
ORIGPASS=`echo $ORIGPASS | cut -d"$" -f2`

GENPASS=$(perl -e 'print crypt($ARGV[0], "zzz")' $PASSWD)
if [ "$GENPASS" == "$ORIGPASS" ]; then
   echo "Valid Password"
   exit 0
else
   echo "Invalid Password"
   exit 1
fi
```

it's ok
The trouble starts here: if I want to **change passwords** in a script I use

```
# username "toto02", newPwd "aabbcc"
echo "${username}:${newPwd}" | chpasswd
```

I can not use `passwd` because everything has to be done without interactivity.

I have in `/etc/shadow`

```
toto02:$6$rLklwx9K$Brv4lvNjR.S7f8i.Lmt8.iv8pgcbKhwDgINzhT1XwCBbD7XkB98lCtwUK3/4hdylkganoLuh/eIc38PtMArgZ/:17469:0:99999:7:::
```

If i want to **check this password** i must use a different script.
*First problem how to have the same pattern of password in both cases?*

i use:

```
#!/bin/bash

USERNAME="toto02"
PASSWD="aabbcc"
ORIGPASS=`grep -w "$USERNAME" /etc/shadow | cut -d: -f2`
export ALGO=`echo $ORIGPASS | cut -d"$" -f2`
export SALT=`echo $ORIGPASS | cut -d"$" -f3`
echo "algo: -$ALGO-"
echo "salt: -$SALT-"
echo "pwd entré: -$PASSWD-"
echo "shadow:        -$ORIGPASS-"
GENPASS="$(perl -e 'print crypt("$ENV{PSWD}","\$$ENV{ALGO}\$$ENV{SALT}\$")')" 
echo "pwd généré: -$GENPASS-"

if [ "$GENPASS" == "$ORIGPASS" ]; then
   echo "Valid Password"
   exit 0
else
   echo "Invalid Password"
   exit 1
fi
```

Which give:

```
algo: -6-
salt: -rLklwx9K-
pwd entré: -aabbcc-
shadow:        -$6$rLklwx9K$Brv4lvNjR.S7f8i.Lmt8.iv8pgcbKhwDgINzhT1XwCBbD7XkB98lCtwUK3/4hdylkganoLuh/eIc38PtMArgZ/-
pwd généré: -$6$rLklwx9K$AIX1bUMAK9bwdd2g3ST5VtXTvHlHXHxnh4Xj.fLdxjaEkAAvHeeN5islid0wtmZN5u1zWQBup./IP8IH9i6W7/-
Invalid Password
```

*The generated chain is different! why? 
How to cure it ?*
Thank you

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: *"I realized that the different linux tools for creating and modifying a user password gave results of different pattern..."* - The digested passwords are salted or randomized, so the same password should produce different results on each invocation. Also see [What key does Linux use when storing user passwords?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/22596/29925) and [What methods are used to encrypt passwords in /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8229/56041) Or see the [`crypt(3)` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `PSWD` with `PASSWD` and replace `PASSWD="aabbcc"` with `export PASSWD="aabbcc"`.

Comment: Where do you assign a value to PSWD? I don't understand they are test scripts, I put the hard values ​​in variable!

Answer (score 0):

YES is good now
it's been hours that I'm on and I could not see anything!

```
    #!/bin/bash
USERNAME=$1 # "toto02"
    export PASSWD=$2 # "aabbcc"
    ORIGPASS=`grep -w "$USERNAME" /etc/shadow | cut -d: -f2`
    export ALGO=`echo $ORIGPASS | cut -d"$" -f2`
    export SALT=`echo $ORIGPASS | cut -d"$" -f3`
    echo "algo: -$ALGO-"
    echo "salt: -$SALT-"
    echo "pw entré: -$PASSWD-"
    echo "shadow: -$ORIGPASS-"
    GENPASS="$(perl -e 'print crypt("$ENV{PASSWD}","\$$ENV{ALGO}\$$ENV{SALT}\$")')" 
    echo "pass génére: -$GENPASS-"

    if [ "$GENPASS" == "$ORIGPASS" ]; then
       echo "Valid Password"
       exit 0
    else
       echo "Invalid Password"
       exit 1
    fi


algo: -6-
salt: -rYc.lGtG-
pw entré: -aabbcc-
shadow: -$6$rYc.lGtG$wMHAM.nXHk1J5sDRmcHeBLW1sRQA/xQcjJSZxkls4BratyWf.KoQST14pPjNWDiUKwfegC96Lhjgjbj4YbZoc.-
pass génére: -$6$rYc.lGtG$wMHAM.nXHk1J5sDRmcHeBLW1sRQA/xQcjJSZxkls4BratyWf.KoQST14pPjNWDiUKwfegC96Lhjgjbj4YbZoc.-
Valid Password
```

Thank you very much, but is there a way to have the same type of password with `useradd` and `chpasswd`